# Generate 2D vector field from velocities in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, 2d, field

Im currently modelling glacier dynamics and I have 2 datasets, both of size 20x34. One concerns the vertical velocity distribution (wi), where positive values means upward movement and negative values mean downward movement in the ice sheet. The other one is the horizontal velocity distrubition (ui) with units in meters per year, which are all positive and thus moving in the positive x-direction. Is it possible to plot a 2D vector field, showing the flowlines of the ice sheet with these 2 datasets? If yes, how would that be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, look for `quiver` or `quiver3` plots.

Comment: or [stream2](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stream2.html) or [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53152-ice-flowlines)